# Can MySQL's Connector/C++ work with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, mysql

I kept hearing Connector/C++ should run on the compiler that it was compiled on, and one document says that's Visual C++ 2013. I'm using Visual C++ 2017 and I'm not downgrading. The document may have been old, so I'm curious if anyone has had any success and what you did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will definately work. You just have to add include path and library path of MySQL to your VC++ directories ( Project -> Properties -> VC++ directories).
Now that you have included path you can directly use mysql.h header to call mysql c functions.

Answer (score 0):

No, for C++ you have to find a version that got compiled with the same settings as your project. You can switch to using the C version of the connector which does not suffer from [C++'s lack of ABI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/portability-at-abi-boundaries-modern-cpp). You can find the C tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/).

If you would like to try your luck with C++, then make sure the build settings of the library you use match your project:

- version of Visual Studio

  - version of stl
  - exception handling
  - vtable layout
  - stack and stack frame padding
- Bitness (32 vs 64)
- Iterator debug level
- runtime linkage (MT vs MD)
- build configuration (Debug vs Release)
- characterset (multibyte vs unicode)

Fortunately the linker will check the compiler version _MSC_VER and will not allow you to link to the older library.